# Castle ActiveRecord something like RowState Property?

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I was looking web for something like DataRow.RowState property in ActiveRecord class, but no luck. I simply want to know whether object has changed or not.

Is there something like this in castle ar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find out if an entity is dirty using [this code](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.aspx).